# Antd styled component datepicker unable to override style

Tags: antd, styled-components, css-in-js

I am trying to override the style for the datapicker today and change the blue box around todays date to red.

[image]

Inspecting the element I find the class to override is the following:

```
:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-sk7ap8).ant-picker-dropdown .ant-picker-cell .ant-picker-cell-inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: background 0.2s,border 0.2s;
}
```

I have tried a number of combinations of that className to override yet have not been able to get the styles to render. Can anyone offer guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the css style to ovveride the blue box is different from what you have done. Do this instead:

```css
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-today .ant-picker-cell-inner::before {
 border: 1px solid green;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
```

You should get this: [image: AntD Date Picker Image]